# Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': A task was canceled

Tags: 2013, error, visual-studio-2013, solution

I have a SharePoint server which is otherwise operating normally, but all of a sudden Visual Studio refuses to deploy SharePoint solutions. It's worked normally in the past. It is now giving an error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': A task was canceled.

I've seen various IIS recycling errors before, but I think the unique part here is the "A task was canceled" bit.

Does anyone know what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset IIS on the server.
if that fix the problem then fine Other wise reboot the all server in the farm.

check this [blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-a/) for more detail.

Also [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c2e214a-20b8-43ff-a52a-4ec6b8eaab51/getting-error-message-a-task-was-canceled-while-deploying-solution-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment) one.

Comment: I have tried rebooting. The "A task was canceled" part is not a very common error. I haven't found any resources on this.